# Trying to extract DNA with an incomplete kit

Tags: genetics, dna

I'm wanting to run a DNA extraction on soil and root samples using a 96-well plate kit.

My problem is that someone has gone through the kit and taken the Sealing Tape. This tape it used to seal the plates so they can be vortexed and centrifuged. 
I have considered using a similar tape from our qPCR reactions, but this would be a very expensive last resort. I've tried filling a plate with water and covering it with strips of label tape, but the tape doesn't provide a good enough seal for the vortex.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into a similar situation, and if they were able to find a solution. This particular kit is this PowerSoil kit from MoBio, which no longer exists after being bought out by Qiagen. I called Qiagen and they do not sell the Sealing Tape individually.

Thank you

Comment: I use something like [this](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/15036) for crystallography.

Answer (score 1):

It is the vortex step that is causing you the trouble. But you can vortex manually, by pipetting up and down a few times in the well. Then seal the top of the plate with parafilm for centrifugation.